# Spring @PathVariable doesn't work

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm new to spring MVC. My problem is that `@PathVariable` causes 404 "*The requested resource () is not available*".

For example this works fine for URL `http://localhost:8080/Spring/list`

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/list")
    public String list() {
        return "WEB-INF/views/list.jsp";
    }
```

But this return 404 for url `http://localhost:8080/Spring/list/foo`

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/list/{nameId}")
    public String list(@PathVariable("nameId") String nameId) {
        return "WEB-INF/views/list.jsp";
    }
```

What is wrong? Thanks for your answers

Comment: are there any spring related errors in your container's log?

Comment: I have Glassfish server and Netbeans. Where I can see logs?

Comment: I got such message [#|2011-11-27T22:20:05.965+0200|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.1|org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet|_ThreadID=96;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|PWC6117: File "C%3A%5CUsers%5CYura%5CDocuments%5CNetBeansProjects%5CSpring%5Cbuild%5Cweb%5Clist%5CWEB-INF%5Cviews%5Clist.jsp" not found|#]

Comment: looks like it can't find your list.jsp. Which is strange since the other mapping works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message says it all. Since it's a hierarchical path it's looking in `/list/WEB-INF/etc...`; try an absolute path to the JSP to avoid that issue.

It's a bit counter-intuitive, I suppose.

Comment: return "/WEB-INF/views/list.jsp"; Helps but why than the first example works?

Comment: @zim32 I believe it's because the path is only a single-level deep, so when it resolves the view path it doesn't try to add on the prefix.