# Path Variable Causing 404

Tags: java, path-variables

I'm adding a `Path variable`to receive value sent by URL. And this is my controller.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/user")
public class UserController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/list/{field}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public void userList(Model model, @PathVariable("field") String field) {
        List<Users> userList = userDAO.searchAll();
        System.out.println("Condition "+field);
        model.addAttribute("userList", userList);
    }
```

}

But I'm getting a `404` error. 
[image: browser screenshot]

And this is my folder structure for `jsp`.
[image: JSP folder structure]

Please help me to find out what is wrong here. 

Thanks.

**Edit :**  And also is there any chance that I can send empty path variable ex: `http://localhost:8080/mvcquick/user/list` and return to the same method?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring @PathVariable doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8288572/spring-pathvariable-doesnt-work)

Comment: @SudhirOjha yep it is. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

system is looking for `mvcquick/WEB-INF/jsp/user/list/n.jsp`.
I dont see this file.

Please try this:

```java
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/user")
public class UserController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/list/{field}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String userList(Model model, @PathVariable("field") String field) {
        List<Users> userList = userDAO.searchAll();
        System.out.println("Condition "+field);
        model.addAttribute("userList", userList);
        return "user/list"; // added line. Alos return type to String
    }
```

Comment: yeah I get that. I  want to know how to set `n` only as a parameter?

Comment: as mentioned in the modified code:
- Change return type to String
- Return the path to jsp

Answer (score 0):

Please try with below option.

```
@PathVariable(name="field",required=true)
```

Comment: If I tried  ` public void userList(Model model, @PathVariable(name="field")) { ` then I get a `illigal start of type ` compilation error.

Comment: What is type of "field"?

Comment: it is supposed to be string like I mentioned in the question

Comment: I suppose that there is problem to convert type of "field". If it is string then it will automatically convert to String by [@PathVariable(name="field",required=true) String field] But if it's comes different type then put that type.

Comment: So what should I do

Comment: Please check what type for "field" comes in real time.

Comment: By testing you can get that.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is looking for n.jsp inside your ".jsp" files. Please make sure that while sending **id or attributes** you are sending properly.

[See this link for sending data(SO)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28333860/spring-pass-parameters-through-link)

Comment: are you passing "field" data using anchor <a> tag or using c:url?

Answer (score 0):

Notice the error says n.jsp is not found. It means you're not returning the view name from the controller - I assume it's list.jsp. To change this, give a return value of String pointing to your list.jsp file. So try using

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/list/{field}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String userList(Model model, @PathVariable("field") String field) {
        List<Users> userList = userDAO.searchAll();
        System.out.println("Condition "+field);
        model.addAttribute("userList", userList);
        return "jsp/user/list.jsp"; // Path root must be from WEB-INF
    }
```